# How to change size of the RadioGroup on the Layout?

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I'm new one in Android and don't know how to change size of my `RadioGroup`. When I trying to make it smaller my `radioButtons` disappear and it looks like  second picture. I want that `radioGroup` don't cover `editText`. How can I make it?Thanks for helping[image: ![How it looks in AndroidStudio]]

> ***Here is my xml***

```
   <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:id="@+id/constraintMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">
    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/rgSex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbMen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                android:text="Чоловік"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.39"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbWomen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
                android:text="Жінка"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.781"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </RadioGroup>
   
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post your XML code

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code

1. Remove marginTop from both radio button

   android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
2. provide Radio 
   Group top constraint to edit text, not with parent

   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

In Radio Group Change this with your edit text id

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
```

Comment: Man, you are the best! Thanks a lot)

Comment: @GenadiyNaumov happy to help you.

Comment: @GenadiyNaumov if answer helped you then you may also accept it as right answer